# how to find lost GBytes in linux

Tags: linux

I have to partitions / and /home
When I execute `du --max-depth=1 -h` I've got:

```
(...)
171G ./home
(...)
180G .
```

So / should takes 9G. But i takes 20G. Where are 11G??

(I checked /home on root partition - it is empty)

Comment: well...  after reboot size magicaly changed... What could be the reason?

Comment: Can be /var files that were removed but not taken into account.

Comment: There are probably *a lot* of Q/A here about this problem: it's often due tu deleted log files during log rotation, but there are a lot of possible reasons

Comment: Once you rebooted, evidence disappeared. You might have to wait a few days to get it back if the cause is not fixed heh. A good test is (as root user) `lsof -n |grep -Ew 'DEL|deleted'` . Some deleted files are normal, some aren't. a deleted .log file is usually the culprit or rather the combination of log rotation + application logging.